# Do we really need to capitalize usernames?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, profile-page, display-names

I have just noticed that on couple communities ([ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/32854/tohecz), [Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/7662/tohecz), [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/37245/tohecz) and maybe others), the username is written in all-caps in the profile page. I would like to ask whether this is really necessary.

From what I have tried to get from Data Explorer, around 15-20% of users have a username consisting only of lowercase letters and such that it's not of form `user...` so they chose it intentionally.

Therefore, please follow the capitalization of the usernames as the people indicated in the user profiles:

[image]

Complete list of sites that have this "feature" as of 18 Feb 2015:

- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)
- [ExpressionEngine® Answers](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)
- [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)
- [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)
- [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)
- [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)

Comment: The capitalization happens in CSS using `text-transform`. You could probably fix it with a user script?

Comment: @StevenV But this profile  is not just for the user himself. If user links to say, their [Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31545/pieter-goosen) profile from personal page, the impression visitors will get is that PIETER GOOSEN is how the user types his name. Some might consider this less than professional.

Comment: @StevenV Nice idea, but it will only change my username on my screen, not no the screens of other people. :(

Comment: to the close votee: This covers several sites at once, and it should be made clear whether specific site designs can allow for all-caps usernames or can not. This is something that has to be done on the SE level, and not on the per-site one.

Comment: My name is TRiG, and that small *i* is important to me.

Comment: +1; though note that this is not an issue on MSE: http://i.stack.imgur.com/C4kf9.png, http://i.stack.imgur.com/cTWey.png

Comment: From meta.workplace, [all caps in the user profile](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2396/all-caps-in-the-user-profile) (no, I didn't like it there either)

Comment: Site-specific request on a recently graduated site: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1651/49.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

During the recent [site conversions to a new LESS framework](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed), we update the CSS to no longer uppercase usernames on the user profile page.

Answer (score 12):

This is being fixed now. Stand by. We are in the middle of converting some of the older sites to a new CSS framework, so they may take a little longer.