# List of communities with base css updates completed

Tags: discussion, design, announcements

> **By January 2016, All communities have been updated**

---

The design team has been rolling out design updates to sites as part of network-wide update to a new base css framework. The updates allow us to:

- Use `.svg` sprites for retina displays
- Fix layout bugs globally
- More easily add new features to all of our sites in the future
- <strike>Synthesize healthy, nutritive rations to feed employees from a small, battery-powered, toaster-sized device.</strike>
- Roll out the new (2015) Profile/Activity pages

As sites get updated, the designer who did the work posts on the local Meta, so the community knows the change is live, and can provide any relevant feedback.  They'll update this page too.

## Done

- [All beta sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/users/current)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/current)
- [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/users/current)
- [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/current) (Apple)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Movies and TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Expression Engine](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current)
- [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/users/current)
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Wordpress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Area 51 Discussion Zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/current)

## On Deck

(I'm told this is a well-known "sports" metaphor.)

The order of this list is random (it is not the order in which the new design will be rolled out):

- Looks like we are all done now...

## Not Planned

Not scheduled for the redesign or the new user page:

- [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/current)

Comment: Poor Area 51. Always being left out of the game.

Comment: New profile is (now) showing up on Engineering and the other beta sites that I checked.

Comment: I'll be over here waiting for Sci-fi.SE to join the future...

Comment: @ShadowWizard Area 51's Discussion Zone (_not_ the Staging Zone) has been included in today's roll-out, so maybe it should be in the "Done" category? However, it is [quite broken](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/users/78536/johnb?tab=profile), so I'm not sure if that counts as "done". Anyway, [I've added it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253532/216955) to the master list of bugs.

Comment: @JohnB most likely an oversight, but only Jaydles can tell for sure.

Comment: I thought that only MathOverflow lacked a space, and yet I see you've also written ServerFault without one.

Comment: It weirdly makes a lot of sense that UserExperience would be among the first to get the update.

Comment: So I take it the On Deck rollout is on a six-to-eight-weeks timeline?

Comment: @E.P. which is code for 6-8 months :p

Comment: Please make skeptics not suck, please make skeptics not suck, please make skeptics not suck... ;-))))

Comment: So hows it going guys?

Comment: @Pureferret - Answer, came there none...

Comment: hi is there any news on when Security.SE is getting the new profile?  Looks v.shiny and would nice to have!

Comment: So, at the current rate of ~6 sites/month (and assuming there's 6 sites which were done in May/June that just haven't been updated on the list yet) we're looking at completion some time around early/mid-September?

Comment: Surprised the sites weren't ordered / prioritized according to size / traffic / community. By any of those metrics, there are quite a few that would be expected to be done ahead of several of those already finished...

Comment: @AviD I'm guessing there's additional factors of how complex / different from the base template the existing CSS is that needs to be changed over. From the description given, I'm guessing the current stylesheets are full forks which need careful merging, and the new ones are more like overlays on top of a flexible base. Those with only a few changes in the "old" CSS can easily be replicated on top of the new framework, but those that had heavy editing will need more careful attention.

Comment: We were cranking on these, but some other design stuff that was more time sensitive slowed the rollout a bit.  You should see these picking up pace again pretty soon.

Comment: @Jaydles yay! Refreshing now.... Trying again... Again... Hmm, that's odd...

Comment: @Jaydles `watch curl "https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/current"`

Comment: It's like someone looked up the sites I've been active on recently and moved them to the back of the line.

Comment: Well, at least I can still figure out how old I am on Area 51 :D

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ The user profile on Stack Apps looks old to me.

Comment: @NormalHuman I was wrong at that time, but [it's changed *now*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SJput.png)!

Comment: @Oded what about [Area 51 Discussion Zone](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/users/current)? It's separate from Area 51 itself, so is it planned for update? (previous comment I posted was ignored)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - it will certainly be part of the .less refactor. Don't know what the profile page plans are, but probably will get the new one too.

Comment: Thanks @Oded, I added it to the "On Deck" list

Comment: @Oded now that it's all done, maybe close/lock it? (e.g. historical lock might fit in my  opinion)