# The question is misaligned, too far to the right

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This is happening on all three trilogy sites. It is also happening at Ask Ubuntu and Home Improvement, as well as on the beta sites Crypto and Expatriates, but it is *not* happening at Travel. Those were the only sites I checked.

The question itself, votecell and user card are pushed over to the right about 24 pixels relative to where they used to be yesterday, and where the answers still are.

In [the example below](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29663198/1068283), I can see in Chrome's console that td.votecell in the *answer* is 61px wide, while td.votecell in the *question* is 109px wide.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: It happens on the [sites with base css updates completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253359). As explained there: _The updates allow us to... More easily add new bugs to all of our sites in the future_.

Comment: But it was not happening four hours ago, the last time I looked.

Comment: The culprit seems to be the `div.statscontainer` element which isn't present on pages that I had open from before the breakage. Its width and margins (total width of 94px) are what's pushing questions to the right.

Comment: i was actual just about to post my question to this. i think it's kinda excessive the amount of white space if this apart of a design update

Comment: Yes, the change is very recent, about 20 minutes ago. Someone introduced a bug in the common LESS  code underlying all renovated sites.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290382/the-vote-count-separator-between-up-and-downvotes-when-viewing-votes-is-off-cent

Comment: I may have just run into this issue on stats.SE; the problem pushed exactly one (critical) symbol just far enough right that I didn't see it (overlapped by sidebar stuff when I used ctrl+ to temporarily make the text a tad larger), critically shifting the meaning. It wasn't until I copypasted the text to explain the question was ambiguous that I saw the symbol.

Comment: Also on [Physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6696/can-you-please-center-the-site-like-all-other-stackexchange-sites).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[image]

I made some changes earlier around the rendering code for the voting arrows.  Accidentally introduced a new div (as [noted in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253550/the-question-is-misaligned-too-far-to-the-right#comment828122_253550)) into the question page.

A fix is rolling out across the network.

Comment: Looks fixed now.

Comment: Let's be honest, a bit of unwanted *gap* is not the worst problem someone could mistakenly introduce...

Answer (score 6):

I think I've found the same thing on SF&F:

[image: Screenshot of the site]

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36

[SF&F bug report](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6811/17815)

Comment: Yes, that looks like the same misalignment.

Comment: Yeah, this is present on all sites I've visited in the last hour or so, but wasn't a few hours ago.