# How to get a new profile page for our community?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page

I really like the intuitive profile page of Meta Stack Exchange. Is there a way to upgrade the same in a different community, for example, *[Ask Patents](http://patents.stackexchange.com)*?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is a correct dup @PatrickHofman It is for sure related but if you didn't find the New profile pages are out you never link the profile page to the css overhaul.

Comment: @rene Agreed. Maybe that post should be updated to reflect that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I was unable to narrow it via search thanks for headsup, initially i thought moderator develops it like community background logo etc.

Comment: No. Moderators 'just' moderate. The site design is done by SE inc.

Comment: They even hired new designers to work on the backlog of site designs

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of sites waiting to graduate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to request this. It will rollout eventually to all sites.

The process is explained in [New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list) but if your site can have the new profile depends on if the new CSS framework is rolled out as indicated by Oded:

> The new design is dependent on a SE network-wide update (a new base css framework) that the design team have been working on. This is an ongoing effort and we will be launching the new pages as sites are moved to the new design.

The list of sites and it's progress can be tracked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed). <s>Ask Patents is the last in the list *On Deck* but I'm not sure if that means you'll come last</s>. The list is empty, all sites that were eligible are now updated. <s>Give it another 6-8 weeks.</s> Took only a little bit over 6 to 8 months.