# "How to delete my account" page is outdated

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, help-center

The ["How to delete my account"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) page seems to be outdated, since the profile pages were updated.

Only minor edits in text and a new screenshot should be needed:

[image]

Comment: Also, that seems to be a very old theme... (if not from another site)

Comment: Can't you edit this yourself as a CM? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, and users making smart remarks can be removed from the database at an instant, your choice...

Comment: @rene actually CM can't touch the database directly so I'm safe... :-P

Comment: @ShadowWizard Indeed I can, and have done so. I just reported it here before doing so because it was another user who noticed this and told us about it via the contact us page. I realise it's a rather trivial change, but I thought it'd be best to keep a paper trail.

Comment: That's a first... guess it's better than just changing silently so kudos! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page has been updated to reflect the mentioned changes, also taking into account the fact that the new user pages have only been rolled to sites that have had their base css updated. Other sites still have the older page, as listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed).

Comment: Don't forget that the new user pages have only been rolled to sites that have had their base css updated. Other sites still have the older page, as listed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed)

Comment: @Oded isn't it possible to have different help page for each site, showing the old page in sites that don't have the new design yet?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - it is possible, just a bit maintenance heavy (i.e would require an override on each such site and its meta, to be removed when the new css is live there). But having the page show the two options (for now), works better in that respect.