# Help center still not completely updated to reflect new profile pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, help-center

Some parts of the help center have been updated to reflect the new profile pages e.g. [How to delete my account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255899/how-to-delete-my-account-page-is-outdated)

Other parts have not however.

- [edit credentials](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials) still shows the old profile page layout in the screenshot
- [interesting topics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) still talks about the "prefs tab of your user profile" rather than the Preferences option within Edit Profile & Settings

Note that some sites still do have the older layout so any text or screenshots needs to be added to rather than replaced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with the other post, the pages have been updated to reflect the mentioned changes in the profile pages, also taking into consideration that not all sites have the new design rolled out.