# Will CSS Update address Title Case in Question stats for sites not yet updated?

Tags: support, design

On the Meta for GIS SE, a user has asked whether [Inappropriate use of Title Case in question stats (Asked / Viewed / Active)?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3954/inappropriate-use-of-title-case-in-question-stats-asked-viewed-active) can be addressed.

I have found that the same issue does not occur here, or at [Genealogy & Family History SE](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com).  I know that Meta SE and Genealogy have the new CSS already applied whereas GIS does not.

GIS is on the list to get the new profile pages but as mentioned at

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/

it needs a CSS update and it is in the half of sites that are awaiting theirs:

[List of communities with base css updates completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed)

Will the Title Case in Question stats issue for GIS (and any other sites that may have it) be addressed automatically once the CSS Update occurs for it?