# Problems with SF&F and Seasoned Advice SE CSS

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There are some pretty substantial issues with the display on SF&F SE.  Names are showing up in blue instead of red, profiles are aligned incorrectly (all the text is appearing in a single column on the left hand side of the page, rather than in two columns, one on each side).

The same problem is occurring on Seasoned Advice SE, and apparently both SF&F and Seasoned Advice are among the SE sites that have not implemented the new profile pages.

Is this part of an update, or is the site going into meltdown?

Comment: This belongs on [meta.scifi.se], so I've voted to close it as off-topic.

Comment: @Doorknob - the thinking in SF&F chat is that Meta Meta might be trying to bring SF&F in line with the other sites.

Comment: Huh? This is a scifi.SE specific question, so it belong on the scifi.SE child meta.

Comment: Actually, [Cooking.SE] has some odd code going on... links just got a lot bluer.

Comment: @Doorknob - Again, people in the SF&F chat rooms are wondering if Meta is updating SF&F to make it conform to the CSS on other SE's.  And as Catija just pointed out, it is also happening on Seasoned Advice.  It is no longer a problem specific to SF&F

Comment: Uhh, only the Stack Exchange developers can update the code for a site (and they have an internal bug tracker that lists all correctly tagged bug reports network-wide, regardless of which meta they're posted on).

Comment: Yeah, Seasoned Advice is also wonky.  Same exact problems.  Links are oddly blue, and profiles are improperly aligned.

Comment: @Doorknob - Then why, pray tell, is the same exact thing happening on Seasoned Advice?

Comment: Because the SE devs [didn't feed Jin enough bacon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147574/jin)? ;) I can only speculate, but it might have something to do with the new LESS codebase that's been slowly being rolled out across all the sites.

Comment: @Doorknob  Then it would appear that this question belongs here.  The issue is not isolated to a single site.  Apparently both SF&F and Seasoned Advice are SE sites without the new profile pages.

Comment: Yes, if you edit your question to mention that the problem also exists on cooking.SE I will retract my close vote.

Comment: @Doorknob - Done.

Comment: I wonder if any of the other "[on deck](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed)" sites are having the same issue.

Comment: This affects numerous sites; a fix is being developed.

Comment: @Doorknob To be fair, it was reasonable to expect that this issue might be part of the network-wide CSS updates, and one good way to make sure you find whatever other sites it might be affecting is posting here. Going through all the sites to see if they're messed up (especially if you don't know how they all looked before) is hard.

Comment: This happened on [Mi Yodeya](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3570/472), too.  We posted on our meta and AFAIK went unnoticed; MSE was the right place to post.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We rolled out a new image uploader today. Unfortunately, the design was targeted at the [new-design sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253359/13) only, and so the image uploader stopped working (at all) on the old-design sites.

In a hurry to get the image uploader working, we grafted the new image uploader styles to the old base styles. This had some of the side effects you noticed. We have since fixed these side effects. My sincere gratitude to our design team for helping out with this in off-hours!

Comment: Thanks to everyone! So nice to have the appropriate colors back and the new image loader is very nice.

Comment: Indeed, I'd noticed the new uploader, so thanks for that too - I'm glad the solution wasn't to take it away!

Comment: the real question is, how many "6-8 weeks" until we lesser beings at SF&F get the new design? :)

Comment: Thanks to you and the design team for getting the fix out so quickly!

Comment: Still does not work for me on *Mathematica*.SE. Opera 12.17. You could say to use a browser that is not 18 months old, but there is still no good alternative IMO, and imgur's own uploader does work correctly. As of now I have to upload to imgur, pass a link to the StackExchange imgur uploader, and then delete the original image. I am asked if I want to upload the image, but when I accept, the upload never happens. Clicking (I assume this would bring up a dialog to choose the image?) also does nothing.

Comment: I miss the option to just provide a local path.

Comment: Hey... I think something killed SFF's links again... they're blue again.

Comment: This is broken again on Mi Yodeya, which hasn't been updated to the new style yet.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I've created a new question for this recent event. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267265/sff-and-mi-yodeya-are-experiencing-odd-link-colors