# Problems with SF&F CSS (Round II)

Tags: bug, design

Scifi & Fantasy:SE Seems to be suffering from much the same CSS issues raised in early June; faulty formatting, messed up user profiles, weird colour schemes:

- [Problems with SF&F and Seasoned Advice SE CSS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259185/problems-with-sff-and-seasoned-advice-se-css)

At the time, this was attributed to a need to...

> graft[ed] the new image uploader styles to the old base styles.

It's reported that this is happening on Mi Yodeya and Seasoned Advice as well.

Is this new CSS error part of an ongoing update or a genuine glitch?

Comment: [Seasoned Advice](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/links-became-really-blue-again) is getting hit again this time, too.

Comment: The problem has returned to Mi Yodeya, too.

Comment: @Anna: the duplicate has [meta-tag:status-completed]. As long as this one isn't solved, how is it a duplicate? Apparently it is unfixed again.

Comment: @patrickhofman - It's a duplicate of a different question than the one I linked.

Comment: For me, either we re-open this one (which I voted to do) or close this one and remove "status-completed" from the other one. The latter is not ideal as it's tricky using an old question for a reoccurring problem, as comments and answers are already made for the previous problem data. @Richard See the dupe in revision, it is "status completed".

Comment: @james - it never should have been reopened since it's been answered elsewhere. I'll flag it for a mod - close

Comment: @Richard It's fixed on Seasoned Advice... is it not fixed for you?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Are you still seeing these issues? The same fix applied to all affected sites.

Comment: @Catija - Fixed now. All Sorted.

Comment: @anna no. I didn't have any issues to start with. I was just a reviewer in the queue. I thought it didn't make sense to close as a duplicate of a completed question. That's all. Thanks for fixing.