# Why do Chemistry and Physics SE use text numbers instead of lining numbers?

Tags: feature-request, design, fonts

[N.B.: I use a Mac, but I'm assuming the following is not Mac-specific.]

I've noticed that, font-wise, SE sites can be divided into two categories:

1) Those that employ a sans-serif font (e.g., TeX SE, superuser SE, and this one).  These display numerals as "lining figures" (~full-height numbers designed to line up with upper case text).

2) Those that employ a serif font. These display numerals as "text figures" (~half-height numbers designed to line up with lower case text) (see:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures).  Here's an example from Chemistry SE:

[image]

Here's the problem:  Sites like Chemistry SE and Physics SE have many math-heavy posts.  The half-height numbers make posting more cumbersome, since they somewhat necessitate the use of MathJax every time a numeral is written, even if it is within a block of text.

I.e., if the poster doesn't use MathJax when writing numerals within text (as in the example above, "0 K", which means zero kelvin), the appearance of the numerals will not only be notably inconsistent with those displayed within MathJax (where they are full-height), but also sometimes confusing to read:  For example, on MathJax-enabled sites,  "0 K" looks like "o K", i.e., like the "K" is preceeded by a lower-case "o". This is not an issue on sites that use lining numbers, such as this site, where "0 K" looks perfectly fine.

Indeed, within text, I would argue that "0 K" on a sans-serifed site (like this) is not only less cumbersome to type than "$0$ K"——it also looks better: On a MathJax-enabled serifed site, the zero isn't properly positioned (it's too high, and too close to the preceeding text; see screenshot above).  It is possible to correct the horizontal spacing, but that makes things even more cumbersome if you have to do that every time.

Given this, why not use a font that displays lining numbers on sites that have math-heavy posts?

And if the standard serif font(s) SE uses are limited to text figures, might not the standard sans-serif font(s) be more suitable for math-heavy sites?

ADDENDUM:
What motivates this is the idea that we're all volunteers, and the site should be designed to encourage posting with the minimum "friction".  Consider, for instance, this comment (which I added to my answer to this question: [Infinite Increase in Entropy when Energy added to Absolute Zero](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/118597/infinite-increase-in-entropy-when-energy-added-to-absolute-zero/118618#118618)):

[image]

Mine is the second comment, made in respose to the question by the OP.  As it was a comment, I didn't really want to bother with using MathJax, so I didn't; my focus was instead on doing the work of giving the OP the clarification s/he needed to understand my answer, and getting it out promptly (note the date stamps). Nevertheless, because Chem SE uses text numbers, I had to add dollar signs around every one of the six zeros.  When I'm focusing on that, I'm not focusing on the content. That's added friction.  And every added bit of friction can make the difference between someone bothering to give additional help vs. not.

With the sans-serif font style used on this site, that comment would have been perfectly clear and readable without the need for the added dollar signs.

Comment: Very few network sites have MathJax enabled... so I'm not sure why you're saying most of them do? Are you talking about sites with serif vs sans-serif fonts?

Comment: @Catija.  Yes, serif vs. sans-serif.  I noticed that, of the sites I've visited, the serifed one have Math Jax enabled, and the sans-serifed ones don't, so I figured the decision to use serifed vs. sans-serifed followed from the decision to enable Math Jax vs. not.  But, since you've told me that's not the case, I'll eliminate the Math Jax generalization.  Thanks.

Comment: In most cases, from what I understand, sites with serif fonts specifically requested them as part of their site design but I'm not sure there's a specific reasoning. The choice of specific font is what causes the problem, not that it's serifed. We could, perhaps choose a different font.

Comment: @Catija They don't specify that they *have* to be proportional text figures as one can with CSS and OpenType typefaces — although of course they should. :) But they're using old-school Georgia on some boxes, so you get its defaults. You don't get fixed-width and fixed-height titling figures.

Comment: Still not quite correct. The vast majority of the network uses a sans serif font (Arial) and a tiny minority (15 or so, I think) use serif, though I haven't counted..

Comment: Though it's extra work numbers, Greek characters, and equations (even *simple* ones, 2*2=4, should go within the dollar signs). As to the "why" for the [typeface anatomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface_anatomy) I might be able to find an answer in a couple of hours. Possibly because the author of MathJax is more concerned with consistent type design.

Comment: @Catija.  OK, thanks for the additional correction.  I must have gotten unlucky in my brief survey and coincidentally opened mostly sites that happen to have been serifed. I'll modify accordingly.  As to your earlier comment:  Yes, that's my point.  If they want serifed, fine.  But then why not have a serifed font that has full-height numbers?

Comment: Probably the best answer I can get you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315762/why-do-some-parts-of-the-standard-theme-use-different-fonts-than-the-rest-of-the @tchrist and I have talked about this a teeny bit but it's been a year or more.

Comment: Eh... that's not quite the answer I was looking for... It's around somewhere... Arial and Georgia are fonts that nearly everyone has so the site doesn't require downloading/installing a font, so that's what we picked... I don't think consideration into your specific concern was part of it but the decision was made ~18 months ago.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't want proportional text figures in running proportional text. If you need tabular lining figures for accountancy tables, that's different.

Comment: @Catija Duplicates: Math.meta.SE: "[Why does the font use text figures?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10317/510296)" (7 answers), U&L.meta.SE: "[Question title font renders 0 (number zero) much like o (lower-case letter)](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/716/261962)" (3 answers, including [Shog9's answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1219/261962)). See: [Typesetting Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Typesetting_numbers) and [Palatino Linotype font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatino#Palatino_Linotype) which has both text figures and lining figures.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Text Figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures) are not encoded separately in Unicode because they are not considered separate characters from lining figures, only a different way of writing the same characters. High-quality typesetting generally prefers text figures in body text: they integrate better with lowercase letters and small capitals, unlike runs of lining figures. See: ["TUGBOAT Volume 38, Number 1 / 2017 - TeX Users Group"](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-1/tb118complete.pdf) (.PDF) on pages 29-30. https://www.revolvy.com/folder/Typefaces-with-text-figures/115276

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for those citations.  It seems many feel as I do, but the matter was dropped several years ago.  As to your Wikipedia quote, you're quoting from the same Wikipedia article I already cited in my post.  I'm aware of the standard reason for using text figures.  However, that's a general guideline which doesn't take into account the particular context I mention here (math-heavy posts, where it's inconvenient to have to bracket every number in a text body with dollar signs); this was echoed in the comments made in the threads you nicely cited.

Comment: @theorist You have not answered why you think your site’s text should have - lining figures not  text figures in running text. That doesn't make sense to me, and it doesn't make sense to [graphicdesign.se] either: [How to construct “lowercase digits” (i.e. text figures)?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11344), [How to construct “lowercase digits” (i.e. text figures)?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/8365), [Is there a name for digits/figures which fit in the x-height?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/29292).

Comment: @tchrist  I haven't answered your question because my entire post was devoted to addressing that question.  Hence I don't know how else to explain my reasoning beyond what I've done.  Perhaps if you re-read my post (and also read the reasoning articulated by the posters in Catija's links, whose thinking is similar to mine), you'll better understand.  Also, the issue isn't about fixed-width vs. proportional. [I never mentioned that.] It's about the fact that the text numbers requre additonal typesetting to be clear, while the lining numbers don't, and I want to minimize friction in posting.

Answer (score 8):

We use a serif font on Chemistry, because we specifically requested it when we graduated and the site design was created. One of the main concerns was that we can distinguish between I (capital i) and l (miniscule L); see [Chemistry site design ideas - input welcome!](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/606/4945) or predating any graduation: [Can we have a font that harmonizes with inline MathJAX?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/592/4945).
The initial draft actually featured a sans-serif font ([Chemistry site design](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1669/4945)), but after some convincing (disclaimer: I was one of the main advocators for a serif font) that decision was changed. Why this specific font was chosen, I do not know.

Somewhat recently the topic of this font has come up again, see [Should chem.SE use Georgia font?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4302/4945) I guess most were kind of happy with the status quo, at least happy enough to not follow through with an actual feature-request.

---

N.B. If you ask me, any mathematical construct should be typeset with MathJax. It is a more consistent look when switching between displayed formulae and inline, and it doesn't break those constructs apart. You know, having the value on one line and the unit on another, etc.. On Chemistry, we even have the mhchem package loaded, which makes typesetting units a lot easier and more robust (It even gets the spacing right); see [How to write physical units](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3286/4945).
*In any case,* `$0$ K` is the worst possible choice, because it combines the disadvantages of MathJax and the font. (Also, it is zero kelvin with a miniscule k and no degree.)

Comment: Are serif and lining mutually exclusive??  I would think that you can set things up to use a serif lining character set.

Comment: @Scott No, they are not. Yes, you can set that up, easiest by choosing a different font. Why the designers used Georgia was never revealed to us.

Comment: @ScottSeidman [There are four figure styles: Lining and text ("Old Style") each divide into proportional and fixed ("tabular") sets. Tabular lining numerals are appropriate for financial tables. Proportional text figures look better in running text because they are designed around the x-height, descenders and ascenders of the lowercase. Lining figures are uppercase. They tend to look out of place in a run of normal text and are better replaced by small caps.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/11374)

Comment: Can you load SIunitx in MathJax?

Comment: Hi Martin. You wrote "In any case, $0$ K is the worst possible choice". I disagree. IMO, on Chemistry SE, "0 K"  (which some use) is the worst possible choice. The difference is that (again, all this applies to Chem SE and other sites w/ that font) "$0$ K" typsets in a way that is conceptually clear to the reader, though not perfectly pretty; while "0 K" typsets in a way that is confusing (the zero looks like a lower-case "o"). And I'll take not-perfectly-pretty over confusing, since I give more weight to function than form.

Comment: @ScottSeidman No. MathJax has little to do with LaTeX, it 'just' borrows the syntax. That's one reason why `\pu{...}` made it into the MathJax version of mhchem; it's not as feature rich, but it is very easy to use, and it kind of does, what you expect it to do.

Comment: @theorist I know we have differing opinions, and that is okay. I understand your point about zero and oh; I don't particularly like that they can easily be confused, but I do not find it as baffling as you make it out to be. Most people who read the questions and answers on Chemistry can infer from context what 0 K will mean. And the work-around is so easy. I've seen botched up posts, where MathJax was mixed with normal text, even sum formula spread over line endings, which made these incredibly hard to read. I'm sorry, but I am sticking with `$0$ K` is the worst.