# Old User page developing rendering errors

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

On the old style user pages such as mathoverflow I noticed that the long comment on the right is floating lower today than it did previously (as recently as yesterday). I don't know if we care, but I noticed it.

Comment: Cross-site dupe on meta.mathoverflow: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2383/help-help-the-colors-are-off.

Comment: It is not site specific. It applies to all the sites that do not yet have the new user page. MO was just an example.

Comment: Yes, I just saw the other sites. Thanks.

Comment: We're looking into this right now.

Comment: See also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3570/5323

Comment: @James, that does not have an answer, this does. There is only one thing that annoys me more than a question closed as a duplicate of a question without an answer, and that is a question that is closed as the duplicate of a closed question.

Comment: @hildred Ah well, other question is closed now anyway, OP confirmed the problem is gone. Votes on this one will fade away :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's my bad. Funny how that works... include one .less file in another without checking [un-converted site designs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed) and suddenly everything is terrible.

Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: I noticed that area 51 is not on either list. It and stack apps were not affected.

Comment: @hildred Area 51 isn't getting a design lift any time soon, if ever.

Comment: @annalear - I was hoping it was because you were working on the new user cards for SFF:SE... /sad now. :-((((

Comment: @AnnaLear Is there any chance of removing the stupid Gravatar thing from Area 51?

Comment: @Catija Not really. We aren't working on Area 51 in any meaningful way these days.