# How do I view the pre-existing community for a current Area 51 proposal?

Tags: support, area-51, hyperlinks, community

A proposal on Area 51 was recently closed by a staff member with a comment that contained

> Please do not disregard the community requirement when submitting a proposal. When you submit this proposal for a site, you were asked to demonstrate that you already had an audience ready to actually build it.

I checked some of the other proposals currently in the Definition phase, but couldn't find links to the "community requirement" communities for these proposals anywhere, even though Question 3 of the proposal form contains the question prompt "Please link to the organization or website organizing this effort".

How do I *view* the link to the "organization or website" that was declared by the proposer when they proposed the site?

- Is this considered confidential, in that passersby who might get interested in the proposal or even join it are not entitled to know what community originally organized it?
- Is this considered extraneous or niche data, not shown by default but available on request (e.g. through an API call or a support post)?
- Did I miss something major and the community link is actually visible somewhere?

Comment: It doesn't appear anywhere, and my guess is that it's mod-only (or staff only) detail, used to determine if the proposal has any chance by the mod/staff taking a look and based on that decides whether to close with the reason you quoted, or give the proposal a chance.

Comment: Annoucement on Area51 which may give insight [Changes to the Area 51 Process v3.0](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27938/144352)

Comment: The "community requirement" is a rule that's often neglected. I think the link is only intended for verification by the team, I've never seen them made public. Of-course, a community could always state their 'other' location in an Area 51 post.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, there is currently no public view of that information *mostly* because of [What's going on with Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263494/whats-going-on-with-area-51/263506#263506), and because the information provided is typically a vague reference to a website or social media, or it is simply *nonsense.*

> I do not have an "online" organization, although I have some friends offline willing to follow/commit.

Without further development and support and enforcement of that feature, the information isn't really all that useful.

The question was added to the submission form in response to recent [Changes to the Area 51 process](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/changes-to-the-area-51-process-v3-0) which necessitated finding communities ready to build these sites before submitting a proposal. Proposal authors were dropping titles and descriptions into Area 51 expecting someone *else* to build it for them. But Area 51 no longer has the audience to build sites without a community to support it, so most proposals gather dust and scant bursts of activity from unsuspecting users until the proposal itself just expires.

Comment: Can the information be disclosed upon request, or is it considered private and confidential?

Comment: It is not confidential; it's just not typically useful. If there's an issue where surfacing that information seems relevant, I am more than happy to provide it.