# Why have these sites not yet gotten the shiny new profile page?

Tags: support, profile-page

I've noticed that a few sites seem to have slipped through the cracks for the new profile page. At first I thought it was just RPG.SE, but investigating further it looks like a number of them have been skipped over.

This includes, but is not limited to (though I *think* I got all of them) [Role-Playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/current), [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/current), [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/current), [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/current), [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/current), [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/current), [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/current), [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/current), [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/current), [CS Theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/current), and [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/current).

This is a relatively small subset of the existing graduated sites. The [last I heard about this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5526/when-are-we-getting-the-new-user-pages), we were waiting for a new CSS framework to roll out (?), but it's been a while, and it looks like it's only these ones remaining.

When can these sites expect to see the new profile page?

Comment: "When can these sites expect to see the new profile page?" In about 6-8 weeks. Definitely.

Comment: This is the [current work list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253359/245360), without time line.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Awesome, thanks. Missed that in searching.

Comment: Yes, but no schedule. I guess it is the SE general timeline: somewhere in the future.