# Are the printable, vectorial versions of the SE site icons somewhere accessible?

Tags: support, icons

I would like to print them in good quality. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any of them anywhere. Are they accessible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vectorial? Every site has its icon vectorial enough since [the great SVG update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed). E.g., [the sprites for Stack Overflow](http://sstatic.net/sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg) or [Puzzling](http://sstatic.net/sites/puzzling/img/sprites.svg).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the SVG sprite sheets which are not quite as high-quality and a bit of a pain to work with, you can get the major site logos in EPS vector format on the [company logos page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos). Any decent vector program should be able to convert them to SVG is that is the format you desire, but EPS is a good vector format for print.

The following logos are currently included on the page.

- Stack Exchange
- Stack Overflow
- Stack Overflow Careers
- Server Fault
- Super User

Comment: Thank you, it is also useful!