# "modified" link in the home page questions list does not contain "?lastactivity" parameter

Tags: bug, homepage, last-activity

I have just noticed that the "modified" link for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed) does not contain "?lastactivity" parameter in homepage questions list:

> [image]

When [appending it manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed?lastactivity), it's changing to `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed/286876#286876` as it should, and showing the deleted answer to those who can see it.

Other questions I checked are not affected. Possible way to reproduce might be question with zero answers, where the "modified" was caused by a now-deleted answer.

Comment: the issue here is deleted answers. `?lastactivity` doesn't get appended to question urls with 0 answers, which isn't *correct* if you count deleted answers.

Comment: @m0sa very true. So you got a plan to fix this? :)

Comment: @m0sa year later, any chance for some quick fix?