# Which Stack Exchange sites were fully redesigned after their original designs were deployed?

Tags: support, design, stack-exchange

Some sites on the network have been completely redesigned from the time they received their original site designs (a part of site graduation prior to July 2015). For instance, Android Enthusiasts was [completely redesigned in April 2015](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/major-design-updates-are-now-live) (see [its design from before](https://web.archive.org/web/20141001004313/http://android.stackexchange.com/) and [after](https://web.archive.org/web/20160831230248/http://android.stackexchange.com/)). Also, Anime & Manga had [its design completely changed](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4264/anime-manga-site-design-june-update) in July 2019 due to a disappointing reception with the [original design launched a couple months prior](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4272/congratulations-your-site-design-is-now-live).

Which sites on the network, including these two and possibly others, originally had one design deployed but had their design completely swapped with another one later in their lives?

To be clear, I'm only looking for cases where the site had a design *other than the basic undesigned theme* and was later *completely swapped* to a different one, with different header elements, theme colors, etc. The [2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed) and [2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes) global changes to site designs are also not included in this question, unless the site received new theming during this time (such as what happened with Android Enthusiasts above; the design team opted to change the theming at the same time as the 2015 global changes).

Comment: For context - would sites like SU where the 'redesign' was basically as close to the old design as possible count?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek No, it wouldn't count. Per the last paragraph of my question, sites redesigned during the 2018 global redesign don't count unless the site's main theming elements were changed, which didn't happen to SU.