# Movies & TV site have inconsistent display with other communities

Tags: bug, design, sidebar, capitalization

I see an inconsistency issue in the Movies & TV site's [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions) page compared with other Stack Exchange communities.

**Right-hand side bar section titles in CAPS.**

In the right-hand side bar section titles are shown in CAPS. When inspecting the element the actual contents are  Camel case but the `text-transform : uppercase;` is applied. The same text-transform style does not exist in other communities' page.

Screenshot of side bar:

[image: CAPS title]

Screenshot of inspect the element for the titles:

[image: With Caps]

After removing the `text-transform` the titles are displaying correctly.

[image: Without caps]

Comment: Well, it used to be [much worse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244847/do-we-really-need-to-capitalize-usernames)...

Answer (score 4):

We already have two topics discussing it on M&TV, which is the appropriate place for this.

First, in February 2015, [Nicael](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/uncap-the-mini-headers-in-the-sidebar) asked that they be uncapped and the overwhelming response was "NTY, we like them in caps":

Then, in April 2015, they were [uncapped anyway](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1782/why-was-the-design-of-the-sub-headers-in-the-community-bulletin-changed), "by design". The answer from Kurtis reads:

> Along with the new profile, we've been been converting sites across the Stack Exchange network to a new CSS framework. As we have been doing this there is an ongoing critical rethinking of which site elements should be custom per site vs. which should be standard across all sites. The community bulletin is one of those items that we felt wasn't necessary to customize—this makes it more of a global network feature and more recognizable to users who visit more than one of the SE sites. Plus it makes it easier to launch new features around the bulletin in the future. I apologize for the lack of communication around the change, it was not intentional.

I'm not certain why the rest of them were not similarly reduced to mixed case but, certainly this should be an issue brought up on M&TV Meta, not on Meta.SE?

Comment: So why did you answer instead of casting a close vote? How does this answer the question/bug report?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did both. I wanted to include the information about the other topics which is easier to do in an answer than anywhere else. Part of the "answer" protocol includes adding additional information to the question, not strictly **only** answering it. That's pretty standard on a lot of Meta questions.